# Como manejar el update en un servicio de spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo una duda y no se si estoy entendiendo mal yo o el update no debería funcionar así.
Tengo dos entidades, una >Receta y otra >Ingrediente, también tengo el >editarReceta
el problema que tengo es que cuando yo envío una petición para updatear la receta y por ejemplo saco un ingrediente de la petición Json(postman), en ningún momento me lo borra de la base de datos, otro problema es que si agrego un ingrediente nuevo a la petición JSon(postman) en vez de agregarlo a la base de datos, sobrescribe el primer ingrediente si es que ya tengo algún ingrediente creado anteriormente, Alguien sabe donde puede andar el problema o si es que mi forma de hacer el update esta mal?

```
public class Receta {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String titulo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receta", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Ingrediente> ingredientes;

}
```

```
public class Ingrediente {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    private String nombre;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "receta_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Receta receta;

}
```

```
public Receta editarReceta(RecetaRequestDto request, long id) {
        Receta editReceta = recetaRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ServerException("Receta no encontrada", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));

        editReceta.setTitulo(request.getTitulo());

        List<Ingrediente> ingredientes = editReceta.getIngredientes();
        for (int i = 0; i < request.getIngredientes().size(); i++) {
            Ingrediente ingrediente = ingredientes.get(i);
            ingrediente.setNombre(request.getIngredientes().get(i).getNombre());
            ingrediente.setReceta(editReceta);
            ingredientes.add(ingrediente);
        }
        editReceta.setIngredientes(ingredientes);

    return recetaRepository.save(editReceta);
    
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

seria mas facil sustituir el listado de ingredientes completo y luego recorrer el listado de ingredientes de editReceta añadiendo la receta a cada ingrediente

```
public Receta editarReceta(RecetaRequestDto request, long id) {
        Receta editReceta = recetaRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ServerException("Receta no encontrada", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));

    editReceta.setTitulo(request.getTitulo());
    editReceta.setIngredientes(request.getIngredientes());
    for (int i = 0; i<editReceta.getIngredientes().size();i++)
    {
        editReceta.getIngrediente(i).setReceta(editReceta);
    }

    return recetaRepository.save(editReceta);
    
}
```

Desconozco si ya lo tienes creado pero sino tendrias que crear un nuevo metodo que solo devuelva un ingrediente de la lista en la clase Receta

```
public Ingrediente getIngrediente(int index)
{
   return ingredientes.get(index);
}
```